# Hide Web part based on list column value

Tags: web-part

I am using SharePoint 2010 and I have custom list with four columns FirstName, LastName, CompletedDate, Checked. CompletedDate is today's date every time. I have a content editor Web Part on the page and list above the web part. Whenever the CompletedDate value is equal to today it should make the web part to hide. Can some one help me on how to approach this through Jquery. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Eric Alexander it is completely different from what i have asked on InfoPath form. I am trying to get values of the list and want to compare dates and hide different web-part. And the earlier answer for the InfoPath form question was to make the view to be shown which is completely different from this one. Thanks.

Comment: To get Completed date using jquery                                                                           var dateSelected = $('input[id*="ff_CompletedDate"]');